# How to prevent the file access from public in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication, laravel-controller, laravel-filesystem

I still a newbie in Laravel. Please help me to solve my issue. I stuck on to prevent the file from the public. I trying to make the file access from public to private in Laravel 7.

I put all of the links in the auth it made all of the links required access before using it. I was tried to access some links to create a record. I can't do it and the system required the auth but when I use the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/actions/filename.something without log-in to access the image file. I still can see the file.

**This is my route**

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth', 'administrator']], function () {

```
//Action
Route::get('/addAction', 'admin\ActionController@create');
Route::get('/deleteAction/{id}', 'admin\ActionController@delete');
Route::get('editAction/{id}', 'admin\ActionController@edit');
Route::post('/addAction', 'admin\ActionController@store');
Route::post('/updateAction/{id}', 'admin\ActionController@update');
Route::get('/allAction', 'admin\ActionController@index');
Route::get('/delete/actionImage/{id}', 'admin\ActionController@deleteimages');
```

});

**This is the controller that I use to store the data to the database and the image to the file path.**

```
public function index(){
    return view('admin.allAction')
    ->with('actions',Action::all())
    ->with('challenges',Challenge::all())
    ->with('users',User::all())
    ->with('status',Status::all())
    ->with('images',Images::all());
}

public function create(){

    $users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('role','2')
    ->get();

    return view('admin.addAction')
    ->with('users', $users)
    ->with('status',Status::all());

public function store(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:188',
        'objective' => 'string|max:888',
        'images' => 'required',
        'images.*' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:8000',
    ]);

    // Insert Data to Table
    $action=new Action();
    $action->name=$request->name;
    $action->objective=$request->objective;
    $action->status_id=$request->status_id;
    $action->owner_id=$request->owner_id;
    $action->challenge_id=$request->challenge_id;
    /*dd($action);*/

    $action->save();

    if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
        $images = $request->file('images');

        foreach($images as $image) {
            $name = time().'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $name = str_replace(' ','-',$name);
            /*$path =*/ $image->storeAs('actions', $name, 'public');

            Images::insert([ /*OrUpdate*/
                'name' => $name,
                'action_id' => $action->id,
              ]);
        }
     }

    Session()->flash("success", "Success!");
    return redirect('/admin/addAction');
```

My **filesystem.php**

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
                'private' => 0600,
            ],
            'dir' => [
                'public' => 0775,
                'private' => 0700,
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

I never do private file before I don't know how to do it. I tried to search how to on the internet but I still can't make it possible.

Thank you for all of the comments in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I did it already but I copy the URL to access the file. I still can access it.

Comment: you can access only `public` dir from url and if your link your `storage` folder to public folder then you can access from url

Comment: Could you give more information? I never do the private file before. If I wanna link the private file what I should do? Create the new folder outside the public folder and store the file? after that what I should do with controller and filesystem.php in the config?